# How to use Onenote 2016 as an OCR on a PC

Tags: windows, ocr, microsoft-onenote-2016

*Note I'm using a PC for all this.
I am trying to take text out of a screen shot made on my computer and when I've tried the methods suggested by the video and the article  listed; I don't get the option of taking out the text out of the img

Links I used to research:

[Microsoft Explanation](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Copy-text-from-inserted-pictures-in-OneNote-2016-for-Windows-e633bd8f-0b97-4fb4-96e1-0f081541e52e)

I also did find a video called:
"Onenote 2016 image to text"

Here is a screen shot of what I'm getting (link):
[Img](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5rBmbdm8DVbMmtOYV9kemdYOTg/view?usp=sharing)

What are the steps? I'm sure I'm doing what the video says, but I get no option like they show to select to take the text out.

Comment: Are you trying on the desktop edition?

Comment: I am using the desktop version.

Comment: Could you show me the screen you right-clicking on the image?